# Simply save file to folder in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a piece of code which gets a file from a form via POST.

```
file = request.FILES['f']
```

What would be the simplest way of saving this file to my media folder in

```
settings.MEDIA_ROOT
```

I was looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277281/django-upload-file-into-specific-directory-that-depends-on-the-post-uri), among others, but I had errors refering to undefined names and invalid "chunks" method.

There must be a simple way to do this?

**EDIT**
Upload method in my views.py:

```
def upload(request):
    folder = request.path.replace("/", "_")
    uploaded_filename = request.FILES['f'].name

    # create the folder if it doesn't exist.
    try:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, folder))
    except:
        pass

    # save the uploaded file inside that folder.
    full_filename = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, folder, uploaded_filename)
    fout = open(full_filename, 'wb+')

    file_content = ContentFile( request.FILES['f'].read() )

    # Iterate through the chunks.
    for chunk in file_content.chunks():
        fout.write(chunk)
    fout.close()
```

Comment: Is saving it in the Database an option? The posted solutions you refere to seems about right. Can you post the error message? Did you read the second post to the answer - it tells about the chunck error and how to fix it

Comment: Please see my edits, I now get "global name 'ContentFile' is not defined"

Comment: You can find it in the [django.core.files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/files/file/#the-contentfile-class) Library

Comment: See the second part of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277281/django-upload-file-into-specific-directory-that-depends-on-the-post-uri), and don't forget to import ContentFile from [django.core.files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/files/file/#the-contentfile-class)

Comment: Regarding the comment about saving files in a database. Do not do this. Files belong in the filesystem, not the database. Your database should only keep a record of where the file is stored.

Answer (score 64):

Using `default_storage` is better than `FileSystemStorage`.

You can save file to `MEDIA_ROOT` with `FileSystemStorage` but when you change `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` backend in the future this may not work anymore.

If you use `default_storage`, in the future if you want to use aws, azure etc as file store with multiple Django worker your code will work without any change.

default_storage usage example:

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage

#  Saving POST'ed file to storage
file = request.FILES['myfile']
file_name = default_storage.save(file.name, file)

#  Reading file from storage
file = default_storage.open(file_name)
file_url = default_storage.url(file_name)
```

Comment: Wanted to add that using 'default_storage' is also good for keeping code the same between environments, e.g. the developer's laptop dev environment and production.

Comment: I really feel this is messed up in django or really hard to understand, because there're so many things working for similar needs, `default_storage` `FileSystemStorage` `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE`, seriously? Totally confused which one is for what...

Comment: @avocado `default_storage` is an abstraction over storage backends 
 and `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` is using for specify which storage backend you want to use by default. `default_storage` using this setting for save or read files. You can use `FileSystemStorage`, `AWS S3`, `Azure Store` etc as storage backend.

Comment: how will we use this method to save in another folder inside defaultstorage?

Answer (score 25):

you can upload files to django server : :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

def upload(request):
    folder='my_folder/' 
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        fs = FileSystemStorage(location=folder) #defaults to   MEDIA_ROOT  
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        file_url = fs.url(filename)
        return render(request, 'upload.html', {
            'file_url': file_url
        })
    else:
         return render(request, 'upload.html')
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use django `FileField`, it support specify a `upload_to` parameter, like this:

```
data_file = models.FileField(upload_to=content_path)
```

Where `content_path` can be a string or a function which returns a string.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code to update a `FileField` or `ImageField`. Django will upload the file to `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` per default.

```
from os.path import basename
from django.core.files import File
self.model.file_field.save(basename(path), content=File(open(path, 'rb')))
```

Afterwords you can access:

The path like this:

```
self.model.file_field.path
```

The url like this:

```
self.model.file_field.url
```

Comment: What if I just need to simply save a file, without willingness to define an extra `Model` for this?