# Django simplest way to save file to folder on disk without using a model

Tags: python, django, file-upload, upload

I'm trying to save a file from an upload directly to my folder media/files, exactly as described in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274021/simply-save-file-to-folder-in-django).

Here my form code:

```
from django import forms

class UploadForm(forms.Form):
    title=forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file=forms.FileField()
```

Here's my view code:

```
def uploadview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form=UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and request.FILES['file']:
            uploaded_filename=request.FILES['file'].name
            full_filename=os.path.join('media', 'files', uploaded_filename)
            fout=open(full_filename, 'wb+')
            file_content=ContentFile(request.FILES['file'].read())
            for chunk in file_content.chunks():
                fout.write(chunk)
            fout.close()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/App/')
    else:
        form=UploadForm()

    return render(request, 'App/uploads.html', {'form':form})
```

I get no errors, just a redirect to the /App/ page and no file has been downloaded. My goal here is no be able to just get a file done on disk
like you can do in PHP with this simple command.

`move_uploaded_file(($_FILES["filetoupload"]["tmp_name"]), $target_file)`

Comment: have you tried checking at what part of this it might fail? Add some print statements to check your if conditions work

Comment: All conditions work, it goes all the way down to link me to /App/ so it doesn't fail any condition which is the strange part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember to set the enctype in the form, like:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

That's usually what I've forgotten if I try to upload a file and don't see it, but don't get any errors.

There's a good reference for file upload in django here:

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been at this for so long. It wasn't the enctype this time, but the supplied link help me out!

Comment: Very glad! If I may ask, what was the solution?

Comment: Of course, it was a ridiculous mistake but in my template my form action was referencing the "Success"-page instead of itself, causing me to believe that the example ran as it should have, since I ended up at the success page. When I had a working example I could find that error, and my first example now works. Such an incredibly stupid mistake that I'm red with embarrassment.

Comment: Thanks! I've done the exact same thing before - glad you found it.