# convert a docx/pdf file to text file automatically after saving a new model in a django class based view

Tags: python, django

I'm setting up a django application for applying online, my model contains some charfields and a file field for the resumes, what i want is : every time a new resume is saved, it will automatically be converted to txt format and saved in the media folder. the problem is that the conversion only works if I restart the server.

Here's my view :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions     
from rest_framework.parsers import FormParser, MultiPartParser              
from .serializers import candidateSerializer
from .models import Candidate
from .conversion import convertPDF, convertDOCX, handle_uploaded_file
#from django.db.models.signals import post_save
#from django.dispatch import receiver
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import action
#from django.core.files import File



class candidateView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny,
    ]
    serializer_class = candidateSerializer
    queryset = Candidate.objects.all()
    cv = list(queryset.values('CV'))
    cvName = [el['CV'] for el in cv]
    file = cvName[len(cvName)-1]
    handle_uploaded_file(file)
```

here's the handle_uploaded_file function for converting the uploaded files:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(file):
    Dir = 'C:/workspace/backend/media/'
    textDir = 'C:/workspace/backend/media/textResumes/'

    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        name = file.split(".")[0]
        textfilename = name + '.txt'
        filename = Dir + file
        doc= convertPDF(filename)
        f = open(textDir + textfilename, 'w+', encoding="utf-8")
        for line in doc:
            f.write(line)
        f.close()


    if file.endswith(".DOCX"):
        name = file.split(".")[0]
        textfilename = name + '.txt'
        filename = Dir +file
        doc = docx2txt.process(filename)
        f = open(textDir + textfilename, 'w+', encoding="utf-8")
        for line in doc:
            f.write(line)
        f.close()

    if file.endswith(".docx"):
        name = file.split(".")[0]
        textfilename = name + '.txt'
        filename = Dir +file
        doc = convertDOCX(filename)
        f = open(textDir + textfilename, 'w+', encoding="utf-8")
        for line in doc:
            f.write(line)
        f.close()

def convertPDF(fname):
    with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(fname)
        content = []
        for i in range(pdfReader.numPages):
            pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(i)
            content.append(pageObj.extractText())
        doc = ''
        for line in content:
            doc = doc + line
    return doc

def convertDOCX(fname):
    doc = docx.Document(fname)
    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        fullText.append(para.text)
    doc = ''
    for line in fullText:
        doc = doc+ line
    return doc
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274021/simply-save-file-to-folder-in-django) has been asked. Im not sure why your creating your model class in your views file either.

Comment: No it's not the same case: my problem is to automatically convert each file saved in the server (each time the file is saved, it should be converted to .txt format) without restarting the server. the problem in my case is that the conversion function (handle_uploaded_file) works only if i restart the server

Comment: @emnaesca Could you show the code for that handle_uploaded_file function?

Comment: Ok, i added the handle_uploaded_file function to the description of the problem

Comment: @emnaesca Actually sorry, I meant to ask for you to show where you are calling handle_uploaded_file or any of those convert functions. Also are you using ajax/jquery? If so, please show, otherwise what are you using to do HTTP requesting?