# Firestore storage is not showing the image when uploading from django server

Tags: python, django, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My problem is that when I upload the image to firestore storage, it is getting uploaded, but when I open the image I get a 404 error: 
"The requested URL was not found on the server."

I included the code below.

I have tried `upload_from_file()`, `upload_from_string()`, and `upload_from_filename()`, 
but nothing seems to work.

views.py

```
import PIL
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.conf import settings

@login_required
def create_event(request):
    form = EventForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EventForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("my form dynamic details  ", request.POST)
            print("my files ", request.FILES['cover_image'])
            path = default_storage.save(
                'tmp/'+request.FILES['cover_image'].name,
                ContentFile(request.FILES['cover_image'].read())
            )

            of = open('media/tmp/'+request.FILES['cover_image'].name, 'rb')
            print("my of ", of)

            # I have tried all the methods below but doesn't work at all.
            blob = bucket.blob(request.FILES['cover_image'].name)
            blob.upload_from_file(of, content_type="image/jpeg")
            # blob.upload_from_string(request.FILES['cover_image'].name, content_type="image/jpeg")
            # blob.upload_from_filename(filename='media/tmp/'+request.FILES['cover_image'].name)
            print(
                "File {} uploaded to {}.".format(
                    request.FILES['cover_image'].name, "jigarfile.jpg"
                )
            )

            return redirect('create_event')
        else:
            print("my erros ", form.errors)
    return render(request, 'user/events.html')
```

Below I attach the image

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this kind of error is going to be a hassle to reproduce. Also, use a context manager to handle that file.

Comment: Can u just explain in briefly pleas?

Comment: _Can u just explain in briefly pleas?_ Explain what?

Comment: "Content manager to handle this kind of file"

Comment: Or any links or doc

Comment: Be careful, it’s _context manager_, not _content._ Any search engine should be able to find you some information on the subjects, which will explain things far better than I can ;)

Comment: Ok will try and get back to you!!

Comment: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'read' for all images

Comment: Any other idea?

Comment: What’s the full error message? Is that from the same code?

Comment: Its the error from django

Comment: Please add the full traceback to your post.

Comment: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/user/event
Django Version: 2.2.7
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Can you simplify your file manipulation using example from this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/52987264/12232507 and try again.

Comment: 'bytes object has no attribute "tell" '

Comment: If the problem is you upload the file and cannot access it immediately, try to do it asynchronously like described in this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/52181711/12232507.

Comment: The file is uploaded on google cloud but not shown in firebase console and keeps on loading.... as shown in the above image

Comment: It's missing to add a token to the `blob`, check this answer that helped me too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60080133/firebase-storage-error-with-uploading-png-image-via-python-google-cloud-storag