# Firebase Storage - error with uploading png image via Python google-cloud-storage lib

Tags: google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm running web app based on Firebase Realtime Database and Firebase Storage.

I need to upload new images to Firebase google bucket every hour via Python google-cloud-storage lib.
Here are the [docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/_modules/google/cloud/storage/blob.html#Blob.upload_from_filename).

My code for image upload (img_src path is correct):

```
    bucket = storage.bucket()
    blob = bucket.blob(img_src)
    blob.upload_from_filename(filename=img_path, content_type='image/png')
```

**Image seem to be uploaded successfully, but when manually viewing it in Firebase Storage, it doesn't load.** All the image's specs seem to be correct. Please compare specs of manually uploaded image (loads fine) with corrupted one.

[image]

[image]

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 20):

Whenever you upload an image using Firebase Console, an *access token* will be automatically generated. However, if you upload an image using any Admin SDK or gsutil you will need to manually generate this *access token* yourself.

Here is an example on how to generate and set an *access token* for an image using the Admin Python SDK.

```py
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import storage

# Import UUID4 to create token
from uuid import uuid4

cred = credentials.Certificate("path/to/your/service_account.json")
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'storageBucket': '<BUCKET_NAME>.appspot.com'
})

bucket = storage.bucket()
blob = bucket.blob(img_src)

# Create new token
new_token = uuid4()

# Create new dictionary with the metadata
metadata  = {"firebaseStorageDownloadTokens": new_token}

# Set metadata to blob
blob.metadata = metadata

# Upload file
blob.upload_from_filename(filename=img_path, content_type='image/png')
```

Here is quick explanation:

- Import the UUID4 library to create a token. `from uuid import uuid4`
- Create a new UUID4. `new_token = uuid4()`
- Create a new dictionary with the key-value pair. `metadata = {"firebaseStorageDownloadTokens": new_token}`
- Set it as the blob's metadata. `blob.metadata = metadata`
- Upload the file. `blob.upload_from_filename(...)`

This solution can be implemented for any Admin SDK.

**Firebase Support** says that this is being fixed, but I think anyone having this problem should go this way instead of waiting for **Firebase** to fix this.

Comment: Thank you.. though I already found workaround using Google Storage directly

Comment: is this working on python 3? i got an error message "TypeError: Object of type UUID is not JSON serializable" on this line "blob.upload_from_filename(filename=img_path, content_type='image/png')"

Comment: @Martendo could you please post your solution?

Comment: @AnastasiosAndronidis I used standard Google Storage instead as a fastest workaround

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Hey @hemauricio, thanks for the answer. Would you be able to point to a link/thread with Firebase support acknowledging this problem and recommending the fix?

Comment: @Martendo Can you share your solution?