# I am trying to upload a profile picture to forebase storage but it is just uploading a link rather than the entire image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I have a react native application. Right now I have a screen in which the user selects an image from his or her gallery. once they select an image, I want to take that image and store it in Google Firebase storage. I have been working on this issue for a while and just came to the realization that an image is not being uploaded, but rather it is just a link that is being uploaded which is causing several issues. How can I adjust my code so that it pushes the entire image rather than a link to the Google Firebase Firestore?

Here is my ProfilePicture.tsx file:

```
import React, {useContext, useState} from 'react';
import {Alert, Image, Text, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {UserContext} from '../../../Context/UserContext';

import {createUserWithEmailAndPassword} from 'firebase/auth';
import {auth, db, storage} from '../../../Utils/Firebase';
import {addDoc, collection} from 'firebase/firestore';
import {getDownloadURL, ref, updateMetadata, uploadBytes} from 'firebase/storage';

const ProfilePictureScreen = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const userContext = useContext(UserContext);
  const {profilePicture, setProfilePicture} = userContext;
  const {
    profileEmail,
    setProfileEmail,
    profilePassword,
    setProfilePassword,
    profileFirstName,
    setProfileFirstName,
    profileLastName,
    setProfileLastName,
    profileUsername,
    setProfileUsername,
    profilePhone,
    setProfilePhone,
    profileLocation,
    setProfileLocation,
  } = userContext;

  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState<Boolean>(false);

  //...

  const uploadImage = (userId: string): void => {
    const imageRef = ref(storage, `ProfilePictures/${profilePicture.fileName}.jpeg`);
    const metadata = {
      contentType: 'image/jpeg',
    };
    uploadBytes(imageRef, profilePicture)

      /*

          image object example:
          {
            "assetId": "CC95F08C-88C3-4012-9D6D-64A413D254B3/L0/001",
            "base64": null,
            "duration": null,
            "exif": null,
            "fileName": "Omarjandali-profile-picture.jpeg",
            "fileSize": 13727225,
            "height": 3024,
            "type": "image",
            "uri": "file:///Users/omarjandali/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AB8866C8-D53D-47DA-99F2-5CD700EF4EE1/data/Containers/Data/Application/BC734A7E-06AB-4D6E-A078-AAE568879878/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FIOweYou-6d1646a9-9f6c-418d-9753-3ce4dce5140a/ImagePicker/93CBFF4D-6F53-43D0-8B36-6652B937CB1E.jpg",
            "width": 4032
          }

      */

      .then(response => {
        console.log('Image was uploaded');
        return updateMetadata(imageRef, metadata);
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log('Image was uploaded after metadata');
        getDownloadURL(imageRef)
          .then(url => {
            console.log(url);
            // createUserProfile(userId, url);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error getting download URL:', error);
          });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error uploading image:', error);
      });
  };

  const pickImage = () => {
    (async function () {
      const galleryStatus =
        await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(galleryStatus.status === 'granted');
    })();
  };

  const pickDirectImage = async () => {
    pickImage();
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [5, 5],
      quality: 1,
    });
    let selectedImage = result.assets[0];
    selectedImage.fileName = `${profileUsername}-profile-picture.jpeg`;

    // it is console logging the entire image objct from the expo-image-picker

    console.log(result.assets[0]);
    if (!result.canceled) {
      setProfilePicture(selectedImage);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Text>Profile Picture Screen</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => pickDirectImage()}>
        <Text>Select Profile Picture</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {profilePicture ? (
        <Image
          style={{width: 100, height: 100, margin: 10}}
          source={{uri: profilePicture.uri}}
        />
      ) : null}
      <Text>{profilePicture.fileName}</Text>
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            createUserAccount();
          }}>
          <Text>Submit</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.goBack();
          }}>
          <Text>Back</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ProfilePictureScreen;
```

why is the image not getting uploaded and how do I fix this... Can anyone help me.

when the image is uploaded to firebase storage, it give me the following error:

[image: storage terminal]

[image: what I see when I click the preview link]

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60749567/error-loading-preview-in-firebase-cloud-storage